# C - Writing words from txt to an array

Tags: c

I have txt file, which has a line of many words. I need to write all of them to an array. I've looked through many examples, where fscanf was used, however I wasn't able to understand how it works, therefore i was unable to use it in my program as well. So the questions: how do I create an array, which could contain all of the words, or should I just create something like this a[999999] and dont worry about it. How do I write the words into that array, excluding ",", ".", "?" etc? And one more question, how can I measure word's size(how many characters it has)?

Sorry for nooby questions and thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the input and what you need to do with these words? Offhand you use a char**, malloc, and strtok. Or maybe you just need to hash them into integers. All of these keywords would be good search terms. HTH.

Comment: I need to measure first word's length, and print in console all  the words of txt file, which are of the same length. But i think I could manage with the rest, if i knew how to put those damn words into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Untested sample. You should read up on each of these functions. To make sure you do, I'm deliberately not looking up the order of parameters as I normally should an am quite likely guessing wrong on some of the calls.

```
/* Untested Sample of "What it kinda should maybe look like" */
char buf[BUFSIZ];
fgets(stdin,buf); /*read a line*/
int i;
char *p;
for (p=buf,i=0; p+=strspn(p," .,"); i++) /*count delimiters*/; 
char **words;
words = malloc(i+1 * sizeof(char *));
for (i=0, words[0]=strdup(p=strtok(buf," .,"); words[++i]=strdup(p=strtok(NULL," .,"));) /**/;
words[++i]=NULL;
```

BUFSIZ should give you a pretty huge buffer (enough for any *reasonable* textfile). Scan the buffer and count delimiters to give a good guess at the max number of words we'll find. Allocate an array of char pointers. Fill the array with `strdup` copies of the return values from a sequence of calls to `strtok`. The first call to `strtok` passes the string as the first argument. Calls after that pass NULL as the first argument which means "keep using the same string". Also I'm not sure about that second loop termination. Treat this as pseudocode. :)

*Edit:* If you've got the word in a string, `strlen` will give you the length (not counting the terminating nul byte).